# UIBezierPath arc and rectangle problem on iPhone X family but not on earlier phones

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, iphone-x

I have created a Objective-C category for UIView to draw rounded corners. I am trying to implement a Pill button and the function is working except on iPhone X family. Because the Arc is at the end of the UIView, I think I have to draw the rest of the view as a rectangle to fill in. If there is a better way to do this I would love to know. Here is the function.

```
- (void)setRounded:(BOOL)clockwise borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor {
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;

    CGFloat offset = CGRectGetMidY(rect);
    NSAssert(rect.size.width-rect.origin.x >= offset, @"width too small %f < %f", rect.size.width, offset);

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(clockwise?rect.size.width-rect.origin.x-offset:rect.origin.x+offset, offset) radius:offset startAngle:GLKMathDegreesToRadians(270) endAngle:GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90) clockwise:clockwise];
    DLog(@"(clockwise: %@) maskPath: %@", clockwise?@"true":@"false", NSStringFromCGRect([maskPath bounds]));
    [maskPath setUsesEvenOddFillRule:NO];
    UIBezierPath *squarePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    if (clockwise) {
        [squarePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width-rect.origin.x-offset, rect.origin.y)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width-rect.origin.x-offset, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)];
    } else {        
        [squarePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+offset, rect.origin.y)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width-rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y)];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width-rect.origin.x, round(rect.origin.y+rect.size.height))];
        [squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+offset, round(rect.origin.y+rect.size.height))];
        //[squarePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+offset, rect.origin.y)];
        [squarePath closePath];
    }
    DLog(@"squarePath: %@", NSStringFromCGRect([squarePath bounds]));
    [maskPath appendPath:squarePath];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = rect;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shape.frame = self.frame;
    shape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    shape.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shape.strokeColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    shape.fillColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:shape];
}
```

[image: iPhoneX extra line]

Comment: I'm not understanding your strategy. What is the "square path" for? Why don't you just draw the entire pill shape as a single path?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I think I found out what the actual problem was. The resolution on the iPhone X is higher but the width is odd (i.e. 375). So in creating the middle label, the width was even creating a width with .5 in it which  wasn't resolving properly. I fixed this by calculating the label based on  the screen width being even (8 Plus) or odd (XS) and now it looks right.

Comment: Well again this is why I prefer a solution where the view draws itself and all you have to do is use constraints as usual to size/position the view. The solution I give cannot fail because it doesn't depend on any assumptions about resolution, size, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is just draw the entire pill shape as a single path, and fill it. Here is a UIView subclass that draws itself as a pill shape:

[image]

So you see it's just a matter of setting the size and proportions of that view the way you want them, and the pill will just appear, no matter what device you're running on.

Here's the code for the pill view:

```
class PillView : UIView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        self.isOpaque = false
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let ins : CGFloat = 2
        let r = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: ins, dy: ins)
        let radius : CGFloat = r.size.height / 2
        let d90 = CGFloat.pi/2
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to:CGPoint(x:r.maxX - radius, y:ins))
        path.addArc(center:CGPoint(x:radius+ins, y:radius+ins), radius: radius, 
            startAngle: -d90, endAngle: d90, clockwise: true)
        path.addArc(center:CGPoint(x:r.maxX - radius, y:radius+ins), radius: radius, 
            startAngle: d90, endAngle: -d90, clockwise: true)
        path.closeSubpath()
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        bez.cgPath = path
        UIColor.green.setFill()
        bez.fill()
    }
}
```